# Change winform ToolTip backcolor

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am using a ToolTip control in my project. I want to set its backcolor red. I have changed ownerdraw property to true and backcolor to red. But no result. Any suggestion?

Regards,
skpaul.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set these propeties:

```
yourTooltip.OwnerDraw = true; 
yourTooltip.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

then on the Draw event use this :

```
private void yourTooltip_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawBorder();
    e.DrawText();
}
```

Comment: Didn't know those even existed !

Comment: My vote is 100%. Simple code, easy to remember, fully workable. Thanks Nacereddine, many many many thanks.

Comment: I can't even get the Draw event to fire event though Active = true and OwnerDraw = true.  PopUp fires, but Draw never does.  I have more than one tooltip on this form.  I hate coding sometimes.

Comment: it's a pity that it is not working when the IsBaloon is set to true

Answer (score 12):

Add Event to toolstrip and set OwnerDraw to true:

```
public Form1() {
     InitializeComponent();
     toolTip1.OwnerDraw = true;
     toolTip1.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(toolTip1_Draw);          
 }
```

Then do add a method for Draw Event:

```
void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e) {
     Font f = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
     toolTip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     e.DrawBackground();
     e.DrawBorder();
     e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, f, Brushes.Black, new PointF(2, 2));
 }
```

Comment: I have another problem. May i ask here ?? its about .rdlc report.

Comment: Maybe better to create new question in case i can't help, others won't see it.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a Control to OwnerDraw, you have to handle the drawing of the control yourself.

Here's a quick and dirty example (adapt to your taste):

```
Private Sub ToolTip1_Draw(sender As Object, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs) Handles ToolTip1.Draw
    Dim tt As ToolTip = CType(sender, ToolTip)
    Dim b As Brush = New SolidBrush(tt.BackColor)

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.Bounds)

    Dim sf As StringFormat = New StringFormat
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, e.Bounds, sf)

    sf.Dispose()
    b.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Cheers