# C# How can I change the BackColor of a ToolTip with isBalloon = true?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I saw this question: [Change winform ToolTip backcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990757/change-winform-tooltip-backcolor) but the top answer solution did not work...
I set `isBalloon = true`, is that the problem? How can I still change the `BackColor`?

Comment: I wrote the same code as in the answer of the other question...

Comment: The background color is set by the theme selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to modify the DrawToolTopEventArgs in the OnDraw method. Take a look at this post on MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/77cf51ac-1c52-4f2e-8ab8-42c4ba864b7d

Comment: is this the only way? why can't i just set the backcolor?? Why would there be `toolTip1.BackColor` if it doesn't work?