# ToolTip Background Windows Form

Tags: c#, tooltip, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

So I have a tool tip attached to a picturebox in a windows form and the text displayed is fine with no errors nothing, but when I change the background nothing happens, I want a yellow type of background colour but it doesn't change at all, can anyone please help me?

I have set the tooltip on tooltip1 text in the properties window which displays the text perfectly, but when I set the background colour either nothing happens or I get the colour but no text to show when I say e.DrawBackground();

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you saw this question [C# How can I change the BackColor of a ToolTip with isBalloon = true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008830/c-sharp-how-can-i-change-the-backcolor-of-a-tooltip-with-isballoon-true).

Which points you to this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77cf51ac-1c52-4f2e-8ab8-42c4ba864b7d/can-i-change-the-colour-of-the-tooltip-item-from-within-my-program?forum=csharpgeneral.

The suggestion is basically to set DrawToolTopEventArgs in the OnDraw method.

HTH

Comment: Thanks very much this has helped a lot :)