# Show a popup in tooltip or mouseover in wpf using c# (Telerik)

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I need to show a popup in the tooltip or in mouseover like the below diagram. Is it possible to do so? If so any tutorial?

When i mouse over a button or a control I need that yellow background popup to be shown, is it possible?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Short answer for you question is  _Yes! Possible_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ToolTip`, and modify its `Template` to whatever you want.

```
<Button Content="Press">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <ToolTip.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
                        <Ellipse Fill="#FFDA1D1D" Stroke="#FFC3E625" StrokeThickness="2" Width="100" Height="100"></Ellipse>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToolTip.Template>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks it works .Is it possible to apply any style css to this template

Comment: There are no css in WPF. But you can create your own Styles. Search google for "Style WPF tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

Good walk through here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTly0rYQb10

another similar solution here, I needed to do this when I tested it just now.
[Change winform ToolTip backcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990757/change-winform-tooltip-backcolor)

Something he doesn't mention is that all objects on the form will have a property added for the tooltip, meaning you can use just one tooltip to handle many different objects.

The tooltip object will not be visible, of course and you will be able to change its font and background color to look however you want in its property manager.

Tested this and it looks pretty good

```
    <Button IsEnabled="True"
            Content="save" Margin="0,0,0,262">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Background="Yellow">

                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"> Save Text</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock> Save the text! </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
```

Comment: He is asking in WPF I think. .

Comment: Not much different then. Here's a basic guide: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ToolTip.html