# Customized ToolTip Not Working Correctly

Tags: c#, tooltip

In my Windows Form Application in C#, I have many `TextBox` controls, all of which have the same `ToolTip` control/message attached to them. Without any customization, the `ToolTip` was working perfectly.

[image]

Now, I added `BackColor` to the `ToolTip` balloons using the code snippet selected as the best answer in [Change winform ToolTip backcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990757/change-winform-tooltip-backcolor). This does work great to add a `BackColor` to the `ToolTip` balloon, but it somehow removed all `Environment.NewLine`'s in the string message. It seems to be showing the balloon of the same size, though.

[image]

Can someone tell me why this is happening, and how to fix this?

```
private ToolTip _tt = new ToolTip();
private string _ttipText;
private void ToolTipCustomization(){
    string nl = Environment.NewLine;
    /* This text is not shown properly when BackColor is added */
    _ttipText = "The value must be: " + nl +
                      "1, Numeric " + nl +
                      "2, Between 0 and 1000" + nl +
                      "3, A multiple of 10";
    _tt.OwnerDraw = true;
    _tt.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    _tt.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(TT_Draw);
}

private void TT_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e){
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawBorder();
    e.DrawText();
}

//Adding TextBox controls programmatically
private Textbox[] tbx = new TextBox[20];
private void CreateTextBox(){
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        tbx[i] = new TextBox();
        /* More TextBox properties for design (Omit) */
        _tt.SetToolTip(tbx[i], _ttipText);  //Set ToolTip text to tbx here
        this.Controls.Add(tbx[i]);
    }
}
```

I tried subscribing `PopupEventHandler` in which I enlarged the balloon size but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: You just don't like the default e.DrawText() implementation.  It uses TextFormatFlags.SingleLine.  You'll have to write your own to make it look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find a solution to my own question thanks to the advice from **Hans Passant**.

It was as simple as adding a `TextFormatFlags` parameter to `e.DrawText` like the following:

```
private void TT_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e){
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawBorder();
    e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter); /* here */
}
```

[image]

Now It is showing the text properly. Thank you!